# Is it possible to set a form input to 0px height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-transitions

I am using CSS transitions to make a form appear and disappear.  However they do not work b.c. I wanted the form / form input to disappear when it hits a height of 0px.

But it appears the height is still about 4px.

This works with simple divs but does not seem to work with forms for some reason.

Here is the base case I would like to transition down to.

https://jsfiddle.net/1toL8vgb/

**HTML**

```
<form id="search_bar_form">
  <input
    id="search_bar_input"
    name="search"
    type="text"
    placeholder=" Search"
    value="test"
  />
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
#search_bar_form{
  height: 0px
}
#search_bar_input{
  height: 0px;
}
```

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box` may work, but that's a poor way to achieve the effect you want.

Comment: Sort of confused at what you're asking. Are you trying to smooth collapse a `<form>` with CSS transitions?

Comment: @Spectric - yes

Comment: @Niet - what is a good way than?

Answer (score 1):

```css
#search_bar_input {
    height: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
        <form id="search_bar_form">
          <input
            id="search_bar_input"
            name="search"
            type="text"
            placeholder=" Search"
            value="test"
          />
        </form>
```

use this CSS for hiding.

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow: hidden` along with `height: 0px` to prevent incorrect rendering:

```css
    #search_bar_form {
      height: 0px;
      overflow: hidden;  
    }
```